# Inserting text into input field by clicking on an image

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm looking to do a "browse & insert image" kind of effect to put that images URL (all image info is saved in a database) into a input field for submission.

Sort of like how in WordPress you can click browse, select an image, and then after you click okay it shows you an image in a text area, or the url in the input box.

I'm not really sure what to search to learn how to do this. I'm fairly new to javascript/jquery. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: search for worpress media uploader

Comment: So, you're about to get a ton of "what have you tried?" comments, before that happens can you be a little more explanatory? Are you just trying to populate the inputs with jQuery?

Comment: @melvin is that wordpress only? We're doing a custom project.

Comment: @RickCalder Yeah basically so. I don't need to upload the image or anything like that. I just want to click on an image, and it puts a string of text (the url I have for that) in a input box. I'm not sure what to research is my only thing.

Comment: That is a javascript/jquery issue.  Learn how to retrieve attributes from elements either by id or class and then learn how to display your data in a selected element by id or class.

Comment: @Joseph_J Okay awesome. That's what I was looking for, a direction. lol. I don't know why this got a downvote. This site is supposed to help people, and when someone doesn't have a direction, that means there are probably others looking for the same thing just unsure what or where they need to go next. It's a shame people are so quick to downvote.

Comment: Javascript is really cool once you realize how you can control your html. It opens up a lot of doors.  Jquery is sort of a javascript shorthand that has some useful stuff, I like it for it's AJAX functions.  Have fun learning!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the request this will work:

HTML

```
<input type="text" id="imgsrc" style="width:500px"/>
<div>
  <img src="https://placeimg.com/100/100/any"/>
</div>
<div>
  <img src="https://placeimg.com/100/100/arch"/>
</div>
<div>
  <img src="https://placeimg.com/100/100/tech"/>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$('img').on('click', function() {
    $('#imgsrc').val( $(this).attr('src') )
})
```

[Fiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/calder12/re0o0nd7/)

Comment: That's quick and effective. Thanks! I think that solves my issue. lol.